# How can I make box-shadow work with margins added?

Tags: html, css

When I put in a margin it adds 5px to the right as I expect it too, but it creates problems with my box-shadow.  I want the box-shadow to be able to cover that space (white space) created by the margins.  Is there a work around for that? Obviously if you don't have any margins the box-shadow looks fantastic.

Here is my CSS

```
    #horizontalNav{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    #horizontalNav ul{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #888888;


    }

    #horizontalNav ul li{
        margin-right: 5px;  /* Make this margin a 0 to see what it looks like without margin added */
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
        position: relative;
        float: left;

        background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, rgba(181,147,38,0.1), rgba(181,125,22,1));

    }

    #horizontalNav ul li a{
        text-align: center;
        width: 150px;
        height: 30px;
        display: block;
        color: white;
        border: 1px solid black;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px black;
    }

    #horizontalNav ul ul{
        position: absolute;
        visibility: hidden;
        top: 32px;
    }

    #horizontalNav ul li:hover ul{
        visibility: visible;
    }

    #horizontalNav ul li:hover{

        background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, rgba(167,120,38,0.1), rgba(167,136,42,1));  
    }

    #horizontalNav ul li:hover ul li a:hover{
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, rgba(180,105,45,0.1), rgba(180,135,15,1));
    }

    #horizontalNav ul li a:hover{
        color: black;
    }

    #horizontalNav ul li ul li a:hover{
        color: #120801;
    }
```

Here is my HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
       <div id="horizontalNav">
         <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home Sub 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Home Sub 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Home Sub 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Home Sub 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Home Sub 1</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
         </ul>
       </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: What is the purpose of those 5px margins?

Comment: The purpose of adding the 5px margins would be if I were to space out my menu list items.  To see what I mean you could copy and paste another copy of my HTML from the first ul tag to the last ul tag and paste it before the first closing div tag.

Comment: I am aware of how to paste the code. Here is a fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/j4qAf/ you can provide one next time. So, I am looking at your code and your question is still not making sense.

Comment: I'm not good at explaining things sorry (:  Notice how margin creates all that extra space, I would like that space to be covered with my box shadow.  Maybe this is impossible to do with CSS, and yes I should use JSfiddle more often for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want the box shadow on the ul, then try putting the box-shadow on another element. The actual link seems to achieve what you want, but then grabs the top level link, so you might need to target even more specifically.

```
#horizontalNav ul ul a {
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #888888;
}
```

Actually... that's not the best element to add it too. Here is a stripped down fiddle with a complete answer. I also urge you to see how giving the right elements classes, (the fist ul) it makes things much more readable.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/j4qAf/)

Comment: Thanks, strange how sometimes something simple, is something people (me) overlook.

Comment: That's the path of CSS. haha - hey actually, that has some shadows where they shouldn't be. I'm adding a new fiddle to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

why you are adding margin-right to 5px it seems worthless. For space you should  add padding-right to 5px;

Comment: The OP has multiple top level menu items, but just didn't include that code. The margins make sense.